# How do you use the locksmith keychain wrapper

Tags: ios, swift, keychain

I am looking at a pretty robust keychain wrapper that was written by Matthew Palmer
Github: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

In the examples, there is this parameter passed for all requests as "userAccount" : "myUserAccount" but I am not sure what that parameter means in the context of my application.

The "service" makes sense as that would be the specific keychain group or Bundle Id but what do I pass in for the "userAccount."

here is a code snippet of what I am referring to.

```
let (dictionary, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("myUserAccount")
```

Thanks.

**EDIT**
After reading Rory's comment, I interpreted this to be similar to:

```
let error = Locksmith.saveData(["password": "somePassword"], forUserAccount: "userName")
```

and then querying that data:

```
let (dictionary, error) = Locksmith.loadDataForUserAccount("userName")
```

which would return a dictionary with the password inside?

Comment: userAccount will be the key the data is associated with, like an user name, email address or something else unique. So if service was Facebook, userAccount would be your facebook login id. Associated with the pair of service and userAccount will be other data you store like a password.

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Updated my question in light of this information

Comment: Not sure your edit reflects what I was saying. Username goes in forUserAccount. You would only store password. If you want to associate username with a service, then you add inService, where service would be say "Facebook". Examples are here: https://github.com/matthewpalmer/Locksmith

Comment: @RoryMcKinnel Ok, edited again.

Comment: What if I need to add another value other than password, would it just be added next to it like so :
let error = Locksmith.saveData(["password": "somePassword", "email":"someEmail"], forUserAccount: "userName")

Comment: Correct. Think of Service and userAccount as a composite key which has dictionary items associated with it.

Comment: I will mark as answer if you decide to submit an answer.

Comment: Thankyou. Answer posted. Good luck with the keychain.

Comment: can someone tell how you add the name of the service. I only see account and its data

Answer (score 4, accepted):

userAccount will be the key the data is associated with, like an user name, email address or something else unique. So if service was Facebook, userAccount would be your facebook login id. Associated with the pair of service and userAccount will be other data you store like a password.

Think of Service and userAccount as a composite key which has dictionary items associated with it.

Comment: so the purpose of this is if the App is to be used by multiple users/accounts, it would know which dictionary to look into?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for something a little simpler than Locksmith, you could try the following drop-in wrapper:

https://github.com/ashleymills/keychain.swift